# datagridcell value changing but no update occurs

Tags: datagrid

Building a software with data grid, which is bound to a oledb(access)database, using command builder I wish to update this to database. The problem is:

1. When I press enter key the data value is pushing to data source from the datagrid,and updating correctly into database,but when I press arrow or tab in datagrid while editing no change occurs while save.
2. When I change the cell using mouse into a cell in the same row after changing the cell value no updation occurs in that cell(not pushing the value to datasource)
   tried commitedit, endedit, acceptchanges
   in brief pressing enterkey/changing the row (either by pressing down/up key or by mouse) only pushing the value and thus updating dbase correctly.